Use of react-speech-recognition
I want to use a speech to text in react native. The problem, I can't find a way to do it right. I find a lot of text to speech but not in the other case. In another question I found the react-speech-recognition package
and it is exactly what I am looking for but when creating a project following your instructions it gives me an error.
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2> npx expo run:android      
› Opening emulator Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64
› Building app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 401

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 22s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
Error: C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2\android\gradlew.bat app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86_64,arm64-v8a exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2\android\gradlew.bat app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86_64,arm64-v8a exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:42:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:7:23)
    at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:96:48)
    at assembleAsync (C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:74:18)
    at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\proyect2\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:45:37)

Has anyone used it and know the error? Can I find any example project that already implements it? I have seen many references to this package but I am surprised that it does not work later
I followed the instructions on the official website and it didn't work for me. I hope to implement speech to text in my project
